# How i can add Good Morning, Afternoon, and Evening to joomla website

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

**Hi**
How i can add Good Morning, Afternoon, and Evening message sensitive time to Joomla 3.4 website
**thanks**
Example : add welcoming morning message from 12 am to 12 pm, and a welcoming evening message from the 12 pm to the 12 am

like the picture below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPs8v.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what exactly you are struggling with.

Comment: What you have done so far to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quickest way would be the following:

1. Create a own template and then use simple PHP code to implement that
2. Create a custom HTML module, then use JavaScript inside the module to show what you need.